# sendPasswordResetEmail failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-redux-form

I'm doing resetting passwords with firebase auth, but I got the error. Below is my code that I'm using Reactjs with Redux, and Redux-Form. Kindly check it and give me your solution, thank you so much.

```
[// Libs
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reduxForm, SubmissionError, Form } from "redux-form";
import { Row, Alert, Col, Divider } from "antd";
import { UserOutlined, LockOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

// Image

// Components
import Footer from "@src/components/layout/footer";
import Input from "@components/input";
import Button from "@src/components/button";
import LoginHeader from "./components/form/header";

// Utils
import { validate } from "@src/helpers";
import {
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  LOGIN_FAILURE,
  FORGET_PASSWORD_SUBMIT_RULES,
} from "@src/constants/authentication";
import { login } from "@src/actions/authentication";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Title from "@src/components/title";
import { forgetPassword } from "@src/services/authentication";
import { auth } from "@src/services/firebase";

const WrapperContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;

  .login-content-group {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    small.display-block {
      font-size: 70% !important;
    }
  }
`;

class ForgetPassword extends Component {
  onSubmit = async (email) => {
    try {
      await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      alert("Password reset link sent!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, errorLogin, loading } = this.props;
    return (
      <WrapperContainer>
        <Row
          type="flex"
          align="middle"
          justify="center"
          style={{ height: "93vh" }}
        >
          <Col xxl={2} xl={3} md={4} sm={8} xs={10}>
            <div className="p-3 rounded box-shadow">
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <LoginHeader />
                {errorLogin && (
                  <Alert
                    message={errorLogin.message}
                    type="error"
                    className="mb-3"
                  />
                )}
                <Input
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  prefix={<UserOutlined />}
                  autoFocus
                />
                <Button loading={loading} type="submit" block>
                  Submit
                </Button>
                <Divider />
                <Link to="../login">Log In</Link>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Footer />
      </WrapperContainer>
    );
  }
}

ForgetPassword.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  errorLogin: PropTypes.object,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    errorLogin: state.error\[LOGIN_FAILURE\],
    loading: state.request\[LOGIN_REQUEST\],
  };
};

const forgetPasswordReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: "forgetPasswordForm",
})(ForgetPassword);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(forgetPasswordReduxForm);][1]
```

When I submitted it, I got an error as the message below:

=> sendPasswordResetEmail failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

The `onSubmit` of a form does not automatically get passed the value of a field in that form that was changed. It may get an event, but even that event will only point to the form itself, not to the `email` field.

The solution is to store the value of the `email` field in the state, as shown in the ReactJS documentation on [Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value}); //  set the value of the field to the state
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value); //  use the value from the state
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```